# React - Need to call final api only if all files gets uploaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am having a bulk file upload button.so what i am doing now is am having all the files in const fileContents and and i am iterating each file and calling upload api

```
const fileContents = data.target.files;
      fileContents.forEach(file => {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', file);
        dispatch(UploadDispatcher(data));
      });
    }
```

and in the reducer am getting file and triggering the upload api

```
export const UploadDispatcher = data => dispatch => {
  performPost(UPLOAD_ENDPOINT, data)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_UPLOADED,
          payload: response,
        });

      } 
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({ type: ERROR, payload: err });

    });
};
```

and in the dispatch GET_UPLOADED and making a variable true

```
    case GET_UPLOADED: {
      return {
        ...state,
        successToast: true,
        uploaded: true,
      };
    }
```

and in the component am getting this variable and using useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (uploaded) {
      callListApi();
    }
  }, [uploaded]);
```

But the problem is if there are 5 files ,after the first file upload itself ,its making the variable true and calling  callListApi .it should not happen,after all 5 files uploaded only it should make flag true and call list api(since upload api takes time to get response). i heard about async await and all, but not sure.
can anybody help

Comment: I think you can make a new action for Bulk load, which will allow you to manage your state properties like `succesToast` or `uploaded` easily.

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal didnt understand you fully i guess.. i created a new action only. its about after making all API calls only i should call list API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can leverage `Promise.all` in your case.

```
const fileContents = Object.keys(data.target.files).map(key=>data.target.files[key]);
dispatch(UploadDispatcher(fileContents));
```

```
export const UploadDispatcher = data => dispatch => {
 let promises = data.map(file=>{

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        return performPost(UPLOAD_ENDPOINT, formData);

  })

    Promise.all(promises).then(response => {

        dispatch({
          type: GET_UPLOADED,
          payload: response,
        });


    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({ type: ERROR, payload: err });

    });
};
```

Comment: tried this but getting an error uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function. is because its not an array ? is it ?

Comment: @midhunk yes it is because of the same. Check what is being passed as data of `UploadDispatcher`. it should be an array of your files.

Comment: its an object. i just checked the type

Comment: also its not entering in to  Promise.all(promises).then(response => { debugger;});

Comment: is it entering into `catch` ?

Comment: i guess so .. i think its because data is coming as  object.. so how to tackle that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211928/discussion-between-midhun-k-and-sarthak-aggarwal).

Answer (score 1):

try using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).
Chain all your uploads to an array then you can wait for all of them to resolve with Promise.all.